# NHibernate statistics

Tags: performance, nhibernate, statistics, nhibernate-3

Would it be a perfomance issue when I set generate_statistics to true? Or would this improve performance of NHibernate? Should I always set this to true - also in production system?

Comment: Setting the flag on will force the system to do extra work on all calls. This will slow down the performance. If that is an issue depends on your system. It is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the production you should not enable it. As ayende says "It is not really recommended, it results in locks to update the stats all too often." http://groups.google.com/group/nhprof/browse_thread/thread/841fbc918418041b